# Merge/synonymize [apex] and [apex-code]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

The two tags [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) and [apex-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex-code) are equivalent.

- From the [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) wiki:

  > *Apex is a strongly typed, OOP language that allows to execute flow and transaction control statements on the Force.com platform server in conjunction with calls to the Force.com​ API. Not to be confused with Oracle Apex.*
- From the [apex-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex-code) wiki:

  > *A proprietary Java-like programming language for the Force.com Platform, not to be confused with Oracle's Application Express [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex)*

Please merge them, or make one a synonym of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) and [apex-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex-code) tags refer to the same language, they should be merged.

Furthermore, I suggest renaming the merged tag to [salesforce-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex), for parallelism with [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) and to distinguish them from each other.  (There are [126 questions mistakenly tagged [apex][oracle]](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex%20oracle), which should be retagged manually as [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) before merging.)

Comment: I was about to post a request for this as I continually run into this. I've retagged a few questions, but apparently there are still quite a lot left. Once those are retagged, can the merge to `salesfor-apex` finally happen?